# How to pop up the 802.1x authentication save credentials window in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, certificate, 802.1x

I'm writing an automation script to enable 802.1x network authentication.

Remote Desktop disconnects when no certificate is saved. How can I pop up the window to save the certificate? Or how can I save the certificate without disconnecting the remote desktop?

[image: Save credentials window]

Comment: Please explain more why "Remote Desktop disconnects when no certificate is saved".

Comment: Thanks.Remote Desktop causes network disconnection when I don't have credentials saved in the system.After save credentials everything works fine.Actually I don't know what causes it.Maybe related to the windows system user session

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.Remote Desktop causes network disconnection when I don't have credentials saved in the system.After save credentials everything works fine.Actually I don't know what causes it.Maybe related to the windows system user session

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).